# How to Tweet in Twitter using PHP

Tags: php, twitter

How can I tweet in twitter from my website? I am using a PHP script. Whatever tweets I send from my website should update my twitter account. I use the following code, but it is not updating in my twitter account:

```
// Set username and password
$username='myusername';
$password='*********';
// The message you want to send
$message = 'Nice to c all again.Have a nice day..';
// The twitter API address
$url='http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml';
// Alternative JSON version
// $url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json';
// Set up and execute the curl process
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"status=".$message);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password");
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
// check for success or failure
if (empty($buffer)) {
    echo 'Try again';
} else {
    echo 'success';
}
```

This script is returning a success message, but when I check my twitter account no tweets are found.

What could be the problem?

Comment: A google using keywords like 'twitter php' would throw out lots of links. Some links useful are: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php http://code.google.com/p/php-twitter/ You have not added your script yet.

Answer (score 18):

You are trying to send tweets using Basic Authentication (user name and password). This is no longer allowed. There are many examples of this online, but Twitter turned it off last August. You now have to use OAuth to do authentication.

Answer (score 0):

to tweet using twitter you will need a **post_authenticity_token** along with your ***username*** and ***password***.
this token can be obtained from your profile page by fetching it using curl (after you login with curl). i experimented with curl and was able to tweet using curl. you can find my code at (though it is in bash script, it can be ported to php easily coz they both use *curl*)
http://pastebin.com/a5eBcEeP .

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of PHP libraries that support OAUTH and you can use to write a tweet function in PHP and the 1.1 version of the Twitter API here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

[tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) is probably my favorite.

Comment: First link is broken.. Use https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries